# Android AlarmManager to Save Device Coordinates to Database

Tags: android, gps, location, alarmmanager

Hi,

I have a situation where I need my mobile app to send the device Location (Lat, Long) every one hour to the database. So, I have done some research and found that I can use an alarm manager to call the application and later force stop the application.

May I know if this is correct? If not, what else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If not the best approach, what you suggest is one of the approaches to achieve what you need. It has to be implemented as follows:

1. AlarmManager to be set for every one hour.
2. On recieve of Alarm manager call, the GPS Coordinates to be obtained from the mobile (GPS or Network whichever is available)
3. An async task to be called which would invoke a web-service that saves the coordinates to the DB.

**Note:**

1. You need to have internet connection on while calling web-service to save the DB. Exceptions need to be handled accordingly.
2. You need to have GPS switched on all the time for better accuracy.

To handle Note#1, may be you can even save the coordinates every one hour in your local SQLDB and using broadcastreciever, whenever you get internet connection, you can send the data to server.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need tutorials/code reference for this approach.